# How is the data laid out in a 4 channel image matrix in OpenCV (CV_8UC4)?

Tags: opencv, mat, rgba

How is the data laid out in a 4 channel image matrix in OpencV (`CV_8UC4`)?

```
cv::Mat A = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC4);
```

is it:

```
[R1,G1,B1,A1,R2,G2,B2,A2,...]
```

or:

```
[B1,G1,R1,A1,B2,G2,R2,A2,...]
```

or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you are in **BGRA** space then it is:

```
[B1,G1,R1,A1,B2,G2,R2,A2,...]
```

If you are in **RGBA** space then it is:

```
[R1,G1,B1,A1,R2,G2,B2,A2,...]
```

And by default, OpenCV loads images as **BGR (BGRA)** sapce. So if you did not chage anything it should be:

```
[B1,G1,R1,A1,B2,G2,R2,A2,...]
```

Comment: ... it should be -> it **is** :D

Comment: hhhh.. In SO, I used to be afraid to be sure about my information because there is always somebody who knows a special case. So, "should" is a frequent word in my answers.. "must" is something I try not to use :D